# how to update xamarin.ios on mac using visual studio 2017?

Tags: ios, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

The installed `Xamarin.iOS` `(version 10.12)` on the Mac Unnamed Server  is not compatible with the local `Xamarin.iOS (version 11.0).` 
how can i update the xamarin.ios on mac and then install it  ?
i'm using visual studio 2017.

Comment: update to latest Xamarin.iOS 11.2.0.8    https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/ios/xamarin.ios_11/xamarin.ios_11.2/

Comment: i solved it,i click on visual studio on the up menu on mac : then click on check for updates .  just you need to wait to all ur updates downloaded then a button appear to restart and update the downloaded things . and that's it

Comment: always try to use latest xamarin version, because always they fix bugs and add new features

Answer (score 6):

I solved it, I clicked on **visual studio**  on the upper bar menu on mac : then click on **check for updates** . just you need to wait to all ur updates downloaded then a button appear to restart and update the downloaded things . and that's it

Comment: I'm searching for this info, and search and search ... and if I had not found this answer here, I would still search yet ;-) Thx!